Ansible to update the AWS dynamodb table
Team,
Is there a way to Create item on the aws dynamodb table using Ansible?
We have a dynamodb table, which has Attributes called hostID, we would like to update the value using the ansible task (the value get generated from another task). I have tried a few different ways using community.aws.dynamodb_table module  but no luck.  Any suggestions?
Task:
 - name: Insert an item with hostID into the onprem_certificates DynamoDB table
   community.aws.dynamodb_table:
     region: "{{ aws_ssm_region }}"
     name: "{{ dynamodb_table_name }}"
     hash_key_name: "hostID"
     item:
       hostID: "{{ manage_instance_id }}"
     state: "present"




This one is working.
- name: Update dynamodb table with managed instance details
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: false
  ansible.builtin.command: >
    aws dynamodb --region "{{ aws_ssm_region }}" put-item \
        --table-name "{{ dynamodb_table_name }}" \
        --item \
            '{"hostID": {"S": "'{{ manage_instance_id }}'" }}'

